# Unable to download jersey-quickstart-webapp from maven

Tags: java, maven, web-applications, jersey

I am trying download a jersey-quickstart-webapp using maven. I am unable to figure out what is wrong with my command below.

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes  -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-webapp -DarchetypeVersion=2.2
```

The errors I get are below: what am I doing wrong here?

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0:generate (default-cli) > generate-sources @ standalone-pom

[INFO] Generating project in Interactive mode
[WARNING] No archetype found in remote catalog. Defaulting to internal catalog
[WARNING] Archetype not found in any catalog. Falling back to central repository
(http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2).
[WARNING] Use -DarchetypeRepository=<your repository> if archetype's repository is elsewhere.
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/archetypes/jersey-quickstart-webapp/2.2/jersey-quickstart-webapp-2.2.pom
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/archetypes/jersey-quickstart-webapp/2.2/jersey-quickstart-webapp-2.2.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.330 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-03-29T20:46:00+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/139M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-webapp:2.2) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Answer (score 1):

The version you have specified is wrong(NOT 2.2 its 2.25.1). Try to run this:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes  -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-webapp -DarchetypeVersion=2.25.1
```

Comment: In my case I didn't even put `-DarchetypeGroupId`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not with the command but the settings.xml.
I had to add my local artifactory setton